# Creating a Wordpress Template From Scratch - Sidebar Placement

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, bootstrap-4

I'm creating a Wordpress template from scratch and I am already in the process of adding sidebars. But I'm having a few problems with the sidebar positioning/placements.

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IawYj.png) vs [What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWAXY.png)

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong with the sidebar.php or with the container blocks.

But here's my **css** code:

```
/* Sidebar modules for boxing content */
.sdbrcont {
float: left;
background-color: black;
}
```

My **sidebar.php** code:

```
<div class="sdbrcont">
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'left_sdbr' ) ) : ?>
<div id="primary-sidebar" class="primary-sidebar widget-area" role="complementary">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'left_sdbr' ); ?>
</div><!-- #primary-sidebar -->
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

and if the problem is on my **index.php**, here's the code:

```
<div class="row">
<?php get_sidebar( 'left-sdbr' ); ?>
    <div id="contentcont">
    <div class="blog-main">
    <div class="blogtitle">
        <p>PAKU SQUAD
        <span class="subheader1">
        BLOG
        </span>
        </p>
        <hr>
        </div>
        <?php 
        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

        endwhile;?> 
        <nav>
            <ul class="pager">
            <li> <?php next_posts_link( 'Older Posts >>>' ); ?> </li>
            <li> <?php previous_posts_link( '<<< Newer Posts' ); ?></li>
            </ul>
            </nav> 
        <?php
        endif; 
        ?>
    </div> <!-- /.blog-main -->
    </div>
</div> <!-- /.row -->
```

This is my firt time creating a wordpress template and I would really appreciate all the help I can get. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Still struggling with the theme building I see.  Best thing to do is just leverage the demo themes that come with WordPress, look at what they are doing and copy/modify them.

Comment: I assume you are using bootstrap?

Comment: @AwaisUmar Yes, I'm using bootstrap.

Comment: Where are Bootstrap's container class, col-md-* classes? You did it wrong. First you need to build empty grid skeleton. Then just put sidebar do left grid cell, main content to right cell. http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid

Comment: @Elvin85 that's what I was about to point out :) That's why I asked OP if he was using bootstrap since he is not creating a grid layout. What he is getting is expected.

Comment: I see what you guys mean and I added bootstrap grid and it did the job. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pay attention to **Layout** grid system in bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/

Because you need to determine the width of the container, else will be all the body.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      Sidebar
    <div>
    <div class="col">
      Content
    <div>
  </div>
</div>
```